# Software implementation of quantile function for t distribution

Tags: latex, numeric, numerical-analysis, quantile

I want to implement a quantile function into one of my documents in `LaTeX`. Specifically, the quantile function for the t distribution. Yes, I'm talking about an actual numerical approximation of for instance the `qt()` function in `R`, inside my document.

How is the quantile function normally implemented? Neither the regularized beta function, nor the hypergeometric function I can find anywhere on the web and `LaTeX`/`tikZ` don't seem to calculate integrals or infinite sums/products (or at least not in a timely fashion, I've heard options in the general direction of the `xint` package). Both of these functions (including `sgn(x)`, but that one's easy to implement in `TeX`) keep coming up when I'm trying to approximate the quantile function.

Bonus points if you know a `LaTeX`-specific implementation of the quantile function or if you know where to start.